# checking for user integer input with cin gives infinite loop

Tags: c++, error-handling, user-input, cin

I'm trying to print an error message if the user does not enter anything into the input prompt, and if what they enter is zero or less.

```
void checkScoreInputed(int* qaltScores, int i){
    while(true){
        // cin.clear(); here?
        if ((cin >> qaltScores[i]) && (qaltScores > 0)){
            // also tried placing cin.clear() here. 
            break;} else // else is optional
        cout << "Please supply a positive number for the score: ";
    }
}
```

I've tried placing cin.ignore() and cin.clear() both before and after the if statement, but I am still getting an infinite loop of  `cout << "Please supply...."` after the user enters a non-integer value, like a character. How can I fix this?

Comment: Thing is, I'm not sure where I should place the clear(), if necessary.

Comment: You need to call them after the input goes into a bad state. In your code, that is most logically right with the output.

Comment: @chris Thanks Chris, your comment, which should be an answer, helped and made it work!

Comment: The answer provided that around the same time as me :) I was going for the very brief explanation of why you put it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the `[i]` in

```
if ((cin >> qaltScores[i]) && (qaltScores[i] > 0))
                                         ^^^
```

Without it, you're checking the value of the pointer, not the number you've just read.

You also need to call `cin.clear()` and `cin.ignore()`.

```
void checkScoreInputed(int* qaltScores, int i) {
    while(true) {
        if ((cin >> qaltScores[i]) && (qaltScores[i] > 0)){
            break;
        }
        cout << "Please supply a positive number for the score: ";
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(10000,'\n');
    }
}
```

See [Why would we call cin.clear() and cin.ignore() after reading input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131647/why-would-we-call-cin-clear-and-cin-ignore-after-reading-input)

Comment: Oh, woops. Thanks. But that did not fix my problem. I also had the infinite loop problem before I added that last condition of qaltScores[i] > 0.

Comment: should I place them outside or inside the if statement?

Comment: also adding that cin.ignore(1000, '\n') part turned out to be really important.