# C++ Example : Not able to understand what is being done?

Tags: c++

I found this link at http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/istream-and-ignore.html

which shows "How can I get std::cin to skip invalid input characters?"

```
Use std::cin.clear() and std::cin.ignore().

#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
  int age = 0;

  while ((std::cout << "How old are you? ")
         && !(std::cin >> age)) {
    std::cout << "That's not a number; ";
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
  }

  std::cout << "You are " << age << " years old\n";
  ...
}
Of course you can also print the error message when the input is out of range. For example, if you wanted the age to be between 1 and 200, you could change the while loop to:
  ...
  while ((std::cout << "How old are you? ")
         && (!(std::cin >> age) || age < 1 || age > 200)) {
    std::cout << "That's not a number between 1 and 200; ";
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
  }
  ...
Here's a sample run:
How old are you? foo
That's not a number between 1 and 200; How old are you? bar
That's not a number between 1 and 200; How old are you? -3
That's not a number between 1 and 200; How old are you? 0
That's not a number between 1 and 200; How old are you? 201
That's not a number between 1 and 200; How old are you? 2
You are 2 years old
```

I am not able to get how it is doing it > Can any one explain please?

I have doubts with :

```
while ((std::cout << "How old are you? ")
             && !(std::cin >> age))
```

How is it checking the valid entry? I mean to ask do expressions "std::cout << "How old are you?" and "!(std::cin >> age)" , return true or false which are being ANDed ?

another thing which is confusing is the usage,

```
std::cin.clear();
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

What are there purpose ? Searched on google about these functions but still I am not clear.
Particularly, `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()`

Can any one help?
Thanks

Comment: cin.clear() and cin.ignore() is for preventing cin for being skipped, (if doesn't wrong). For the first while, I guess it is the wrong one being asked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The insertion and extraction operators `<<` and `>>` on streams will return a reference to the stream itself. That's why you can string together insertions like so:

```
std::cout << "Hello, " << "World!";
```

First `std::cout << "Hello, "` returns a reference to `std::cout` and then you have the equivalent of `std::cout << "World!"`.

The streams can also be converted to `bool`. This basically checks that the state of the stream is still okay. Nothing has failed. For example, you could do this:

```
if (std::cin) // ...
```

This would check if the `std::cin` stream is still in a good state.

Now let's look at the code you asked about:

```
while ((std::cout << "How old are you? ")
         && !(std::cin >> age))
```

The insertion into `std::cout` won't cause a failure. The only reason it's included here is so that it occurs every time before the input to `age`. The alternative would be to place it once before the `while` and once at the end of the `while` body.

After the insertion to `std::cout` is done, `!(std::cin >> age)` will be evaluated. This will first get the user to provide an `age`. Then two things can happen:

1. If this fails in some way (perhaps the user enters characters rather than an integer), then the fail bit will be set. This means that the result of `std::cin >> age` will be converted to a `bool` which will be `false`. The `!` will invert it to `true`. So because both the first and second condition were true, the body of the `while` loop will execute, telling the user that they entered an invalid value and the loop will iterate round again.
2. if the input succeeds, the result of `std::cin >> age` will be `true` and `!` will turn it to `false`. This means the body of the `while` loop will not execute and will not tell the user that they entered the incorrect value.

Now let's look at:

```
std::cin.clear();
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

This only happens in case 1 above, when the input failed. If a stream goes into a failure state, it will not accept any more insertions or extractions until the state has been cleared. that's what `clear()` does. Then the call to `ignore` says to extract all characters up to and including the next `\n` in the stream and discard them. This gets rid of the invalid input from the stream.

Comment: "Then the call to ignore says to extract all characters up to the next \n in the stream and discard them. This gets rid of the invalid input from the stream." - it means newline character '\n' is still in the stream, wont it take '\n' as input in next iteration of "How Old are you ?"

Comment: @GauravK Sorry, it should be "up to and including the next `\n`".

Comment: No, I just want to know if ignore() discards the delim too , because what I read that if Delim is EOF it is not discarded, if it is other than 'EOF' - Is it extracted and discarded too ?

Comment: @GauravK EOF is different. The end of a stream is not a special character. If `ignore` extracts characters and hits the end of the stream, then it just stops there. There's no delimiter to extract.

Comment: ignore does not remove `delim` from the stream- I just read in book by Herbert Schild - then `td::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` will leave `\n` in the stream - that is an issue

Comment: @GauravK `ignore` does remove the delimiter. [See here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore).

Comment: sftrabbit .. What about `cin`  operators `>>` and `get(num,'\n')` - suppose `string str; cin >> str ` now I enter `Hello` and hit `enter` for both `>>` and `get()` the character `\n` is left in the stream, right ? for subsequent `cin` operations won't this remaining `\n` be the first character of the stream ?

Comment: @GauravK Right, the formatted extraction functions will just stop when the next character isn't of the correct format. But they also remove preceding whitespace. So if your stream has `hello\nworld\n` in it. First `cin >> str` will extract `hello` and leave `\nworld\n`. Second `cin >> str` will first remove preceding `\n`, then extract `world` and leave `\n`.

Comment: `char str[50];

 cout << "Enter a string : ";
 cin >> str;
 cout << "You entered : " << str << endl;
 cout << "Enter a string : ";
 cin >> str;
 cout << "You entered : " << str;` for this code the second `cin` operation correctly inputs the entered word .. the reamaining `\n` from first `cin` operation does not interfare? But if I do something of this sort `cin.get(str,50,'\n')` to input whitespaces .. the `\n` already present in the stream from previous `cin.in.get(str,50,'\n')` interfares and takes the second string as '\n'.. why so ?

Answer (score 1):

```
while ((std::cout << "How old are you? ")        && !(std::cin >> age))
```

`cout` is a global object of class `ostream` and `cin` is a global object of class `istream`

These objects are used along the overloaded operators `<<` (defined in `ostream`)and `>>` (defined in `istream`) to take input (by calling the functions defined for these operators)

The return type of `operator<<` is of type `ostream&` and that of `operator>>` is `istream&`. These are then converted to boolean values. See [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2).

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131647/why-would-we-call-cin-clear-and-cin-ignore-after-reading-input) too for `cin.ignore()` and `cin.clear()`

Comment: Please don't link to `cplusplus.com`.

Comment: @bartek , Yeps i personally dont like them but then couldnt find the proper page on cpprefrence. Will update it once I get it, Oh Well, you did it . Thanx

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz What is wrong with cpluscplus.com ? Do they have wrong information ? (I dont know, I am really asking.)

Comment: @ritwikG see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972076/why-is-the-cplusplus-website-bad)

Answer (score 0):

`std::numeric_limits` allows you to obtain maximum number that can fit in a given type.

In your example, it's passed to `ignore()` function, which basically means ignoring every newline character upfront.

Comment: What about "std::streamsize" ?

Comment: It is the type used to hold the size of the data inside the stream. [This is really easy to find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/streamsize).