# Can anybody help me with my coding issue regarding a dynamic array of structures in C?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic, structure

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct car
{
    string make;
    int year;
};

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    car * pt = new car[n];
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        getline(cin, pt[i].make);
        cin >> pt[i].year;
    }
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        cout << pt[i].year << ' ' << pt[i].make << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I keyed in the input, I can only key in one number and one string. The program then displays some zeros. It prevents me from keying in more input. Can anybody explain me to what happened and how to solve this problem in C++? Thank you!

Comment: What is your code actually supposed to do?

Comment: Use `std::vector` and search "C++ getline skipping" to find tens of questions with the same problem.

Comment: @quinxorin It's a very simple program which asks user to key in the number of cars that he wishes to catalog and key in the make and year made of those cars. Finally the program displays all the information collected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
 for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
 {
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, pt[i].make);
    cin >> pt[i].year;  
 }
```

The reason is that after

```
cin >> pt[i].year;
```

When you input some "stuff" as `year`, you press enter. It will have `\n` left over in the `cin` stream. You need to have `cin.ignore` to ignore that `\n` character.  You may find [basic_istream/ignore](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) useful.

Comment: I think the problem lies between get line(cin, pt[i].make) and cin >> pt[i].year because I can only key in one string which is pt[0].make. After that, the program automatically displays multiple lines of zeroes and it terminates thereafter.

Comment: @user1050165 have you tried the suggested solution? Does it work for you?

Comment: New problem comes, here is the output:2
Hudson Hornet
1952
0 
1952 udson Hornet

Comment: I'm only allowed to key in one more number which is the year. And the output is wrong.

Comment: @user1050165 It works fine for me. I input the following: 2 (n=2)
Hoston hornet
2;
String w
3; Output is the following:
2 Hoston hornet
3 String w

Comment: I got it correct. When cin.clear() and cin.ignore() are moved in front of the getline function, it works. But...could you explain what cin.clear() and cin.ignore() did in the program?

Comment: And...If I replace cin.ignore() by another cin.clear(), it doesn't work.

Comment: @user1050165 cin.ignore is already explained in the post. cin.clear will clear the error flag  of input stream. You may look at cin.clear documentation for complete information?

Comment: @user1050165 take a look at this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131647/why-would-we-call-cin-clear-and-cin-ignore-after-reading-input

Comment: Thanks a lot. But why putting cin.clear() and cin.ignore() after the getline and cin function doesn't work?

Comment: @user1050165 this is because when you enter value for n, there is also \n left over.