# Clear the cin buffer before another input request, c++

Tags: c++, input, cin

I have the following code:

```
int choice = 0;
char st1[N];

cout << "enter choice" <<endl;
cin >> choice;

cout << "enter sentence" << endl;
cin.get(st1, N-1);
```

when getting to cin.get line, no matter what the input is, it will read \0 char into st1[0]
and that's it.

I assume it has something to do with the latest cin ( into choice variable ).

How do i "clean" cin buffer before getting new input from the user? if that's possible.

thanks

Comment: I advise using getline(cin, aString); This will never leave any input behind in the stream + it's type safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use [ignore](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/) to drop the newline from the buffer (e.g. drop X characters before the newline as delimiter). Extraction and ignore stop when the delimiter is extracted.

e.g.

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Also related: [Why would we call cin.clear() and cin.ignore() after reading input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131647/why-would-we-call-cin-clear-and-cin-ignore-after-reading-input)

Comment: What happens, if the input was s.th. like this: `3   \n`?

Comment: THX for the sample, I already upvoted your answer. I just wanted to put this in contrast to the other _"answer"_ ...

Answer (score 0):

You could always try using  `cin.sync()`.

Answer (score -1):

Do a `getchar()` after `cin >> choice;`. This will consume the `\n` from the input buffer.

Since `choice` is of type `int`, the `\n` is left over in the buffer and when the string input is taken, this `\n` is encountered and it stops taking input there.

Comment: This doesn't really _clear_ the `cin` input buffer. As a last resort `cin.clear()` will do, including resetting all the stream error states.

Comment: This will not clear the input buffer, but will get the job done in OP's case.

Comment: There's no guarantee that a single `getchar()` call will do the job correctly. That completely depends on, what the user actually enters at `cin >> choice;`!

Comment: In that case other solutions may fail to work too. It's a different case altogether.