# ifstream.open not opening file

Tags: c++, ifstream

I know there's lots of related questions about this, but I can't seem to find the answer. I'm trying to read in a .csv file (though the same problems happen with .txt files), but the program never actually is able to open it. I know that it is in the correct working directory because it's with the other files in the program that are executing. Basically, the program keeps prompting me to give the name of the file for input, which says to me that there is a problem reading in the ifstream, so it's never getting out of the while loop. Any thoughts?

```
string fileName;
ifstream sheetStream;

do {
    cin.clear();
    cout << "Enter spreadsheet file name: ";
    cin >> fileName;
    cout << fileName << endl;
    sheetStream.open(fileName, ios::in);
} while (!sheetStream);
```

Comment: Did you check the actually possible error states of `sheetStream` after `sheetStream.open(fileName, ios::in);`? Do you have access rights for the given file path? Loads of more possible error sources ...

Comment: whats the exact error? Infinity loop?

Comment: Your stream has entered into a sheet state and needs to be reset.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5131647/560648

Comment: Oh sheet - no error dump.