# Check whether numbers are prime or not

Tags: c++

I want to write a program that taking some input numbers and then check whether they are prime or not.
I wrote it this way:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool isPrime (int number)
{
    for (int i=2; i<number; i++) 
    {
       if(number % i == 0)
           return false;
       else
           return true;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int y;
    bool z;

    cout << "Enter a positive integer: ";
    cin >> y;

    z = isPrime (y);

    if(z==true)
        cout <<"number is prime" << endl;
    else 
        cout << "number is not prime" << endl;

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

As, you can see, I wanted to use a function and for loop.
But this code is getting just one number. I want to loop the whole input process. How can I make it ?

Comment: Please get rid of [system("PAUSE");](http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-61.html) -- you have no way to know what that might do on other people's systems. Maybe on my system that pauses the cooling on my nuclear reactor.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I don't think I want your job :)

Comment: @MichaelDorgan My job is to type `PAUSE --restart` as quickly as possible when the klaxons sound.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I don't know. Isn't  system("PAUSE"); just make the debugging mode pops-up until I close it by myself ?

Comment: @MahmoudEidarous Calls to `system` are very bloated and system-dependant. I just use something like `char c; cin >> c;`; maybe with a message above it.

Comment: @MahmoudEidarous How would I know what it does on your system? How do you know what it does on my system?

Comment: Your `for` loop will only perform one iteration because the statements inside the loop say to return for both the `true` and `false` cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put a loop around the entire `main` contents:

```
int main()
{

    while (true)
    {
        int y;
        bool z;
        cout<<"Enter a positive integer: ";
        cin>>y;
        z= isPrime (y);
        if(z==true)
            cout <<"number is prime" << endl;
        else 
            cout << "number is not prime" << endl;
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Great! Now, I think I can handle with the while loop better than before. It works well for me. Thanks :)

Comment: Keep in mind, this isn't a perfect set-up when looping. If `cin` goes into a bad state, it will skip asking the user for input and loop endlessly.

Comment: Then, Do you have any advice for a better code, please ?

Comment: This give good coverage of it. Notice in the askers question he's putting the return from `cin` into an int? Without the `cin.clear()/ignore()` calls, if the user entered a letter, `cin` would fail, quit asking for user input, and the program would loop forever . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131647/why-would-we-call-cin-clear-and-cin-ignore-after-reading-input4

Answer (score 3):

Think about what this does:

```cpp
for (int i=2; i<number; i++) 
{
   if(number % i == 0)
       return false;
   else
       return true;
}
```

Assume that `i` is 3 or greater. Then in the first iteration, it checks if `number` is divisible by two. If it is, then it is not prime, so `false` is returned. But if it isn't divisible, then function returns `true` (meaning `number` should be prime) -- even when it shouldn't (for instance, 9, which is not divisible by 2 nor a prime number).

The solution is to return `true` only when you know the number can't divide anything (i.e., after the `for` loop has finished):

```cpp
for (int i=2; i<number; i++) 
{
   if(number % i == 0)
       return false;
}
return true;
```

---

As for the input loop, you could put the input/output part of the program in a `while` loop:

```cpp
while(true) {
  cout << "Enter a positive integer: ";
  cin >> y;

  z = isPrime (y);

  if(z==true)
    cout <<"number is prime" << endl;
  else 
    cout << "number is not prime" << endl;
}
```

Then it will continue to read a number, check if it's a prime and print the result, in a loop. You can put a check (for instance, "quit loop if number is less than 0 (i.e., not valid)")

Comment: Sorry. Maybe, I don't get you well, but this didn't work for me. The Program is still getting just one input then closes.

Comment: @MahmoudEidarous: make sure the `return 0;` is outside of the loop, otherwise it will cause the program to terminate.

Comment: @FabioTurati It is outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Really simply: just wrap the part you want to repeat in a loop:

int main()
{

```
int y;
bool z;
while (true) {
    cout<<"Enter a positive integer: ";
    cin>>y;
    z= isPrime (y);
    if(z==true)
        cout <<"number is prime" << endl;
    else 
        cout << "number is not prime" << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    }
```

}

This program will never stop. In C++, `while(x)` runs a block of code repeatedly as long as `x` is true. In this case, `x` is simply `true`, so it runs the code forever.

One thing to watch out for: I see you indented three lines after your `else` statement, but you didn't use curly braces. In C++, if you don't use curly braces, `if`, `else`, `while`, `for`, etc. work on *only one line*. To make them work on multiple lines, use curly braces like this:

```
if(z==true) {
    cout <<"number is prime" << endl;
}
else {
    cout << "number is not prime" << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers about simply looping over the input are correct. I would also highly recommend checking some well known algorithms for checking primality. For starters, I would recommend checking the Sieve of Eratosthenes

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Otherwise, you'll run into performance problems when somebody chooses to input a really large number.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of your `else` clause in your function, and move `return true;` to just outside the `for` loop. Currently, as soon as your function find one number that your number is divisible by, it will return `true`. So if your number was 9, your function would quickly discover that it is not divisible by 2 and return `true`, despite 9 not being a prime number.

Moving `return true;` to after your `for` loop would have the effect of making your program loop through all the while numbers less than the number you entered until it either found a number which your number is evenly divisible by, in which case your function would return `false`, or reached your number, in which case execution leaves the `for` loop and the function returns `true`.

```
bool isPrime(int number)
{
    for (int i = 2; i < number; i++) 
    {
       if (number % i == 0)
           return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: About 9.. How would it return true, although the for loop will divide 9 by each number less than it one by one. so it will discover that it is not divisible by 2, and then check 3, and discover that it is divisible by 3, and then will return false.

Answer (score 0):

I found this [article](http://www.programminglogic.com/testing-if-a-number-is-prime-efficiently/) and it is more efficient
in determining if a number is prime or not by using sqrt
instead of looping from 2 to N-1.

```
int isPrime(int n)
{
    int i;

    if (n==2)
        return 1;

    if (n%2==0)
        return 0;

    for (i=3;i<=sqrt(n);i+=2)
        if (n%i==0)
            return 0;

    return 1;
}
```