# Why cin inside while doesn't stop to get user input?

Tags: c++, while-loop, cin

I'm starting now with C++, so I imagine this is gonna be a very easy-newbie question.

Well, why the "cin >> x" line inside while doesn't stop the loop to get the user input (if the user inputs a character, in place of a number)?

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    cout << "Please, enter x: ";
    cin >> x;
    while (!cin)
    {
        cout << "Please, it must be a number!\n";
        cin >> x;
    }
    cout << "Thanks!.";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.ignore();
}
```

I'm barely two days studiying C++, so I'm completely blind about what "cin" really is. I tried with "cin.sync()" and "cin.clear()", but still no luck.
And I know it is impossible to do something like "cin=true", or "cout << cin".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why would we call cin.clear() and cin.ignore() after reading input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131647/why-would-we-call-cin-clear-and-cin-ignore-after-reading-input)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, your program should be corrected slightly

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    cout << "Please, enter x: ";
    cin >> x;
    while (!cin)
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(10000, '\n');
        cout << "Please, it must be a number!" << endl;
        cin >> x;
    }
    cout << "Thanks!.";
}
```

This way it works as expected. More info about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131647/why-would-we-call-cin-clear-and-cin-ignore-after-reading-input). In general, you need to clear all the errorneous stuff from cin.

Comment: Thanks!, now works.

I was trying with cin.clear(); and cin.ignore(); But no idea what that "1000" does inside cin.ignore.

Now I have a path to follow. Thanks for the code and for the link!.

Answer (score 0):

if user input a character than it will take the ascii value of character so it will not stop. 
To stop the loop enter 0.

Comment: Hmmm?. I'm using Visual Studio 2015.
The behaviour I can observe is: Enter a number (even 0) > I get message "thanks", but if enter a character, message "Please, enter a number" repeats forever.