# How to prevent an infinite loop, if a non-integer is entered?

Tags: c++, input, turbo-c++

I'm writing a casino game on C++ turbo (latest version for windows). 
So in one particular snippet of the program, the user is required to enter an initial amount strictly between 0 dollars and 100000 dollars.

I created a do-while loop with an embedded if statement:

```
do{
    cout << "\n\nEnter a deposit amount (between $0 and $100000) to play game : $";
    cin >> amount;
    if(amount<=0||amount>=100000)
        cout<<"Please re-enter your amount";
}while(amount<=0||amount>=100000);
```

---

*The issue arises when the user (i.e. me) enters a character or a decimal; the program then loses control and it keeps looping indefinitely.*

**Question: How can I phrase an if-statement which requests the user to re-enter the amount if something other than an integer is entered? How can I, subsequently, prevent the program from going out of control?**

Comment: I don't understand the other answer!

Comment: What don't you understand in particular? Keypoints are calling `clear()` and consuming the non numerical input.

Comment: So in my case how do I consume the non-numerical input? There's nothing like .fail in TURBO C++... So I don't know what that means... @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: Turbo C++ is ancient, get a more modern compiler.

Comment: I know, the issue is my school requires me to do my project using this crappy compiler :( @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: There are many SO questions, like your question, in which the problem is that the error and/or remainder of line needs to be flushed after the user enters something incorrect.  But at the moment I don't recall the exact syntax nor keywords to search for.

Comment: @jonskeet Please help O' divine one.

Comment: @JSF It's a pity.. yea :/

Comment: @Kugelblitz Ha, my school doesn't care; as long as the code compiles, it is all OK.

Comment: ^Lucky lol... I wish I could use Haskell :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    if(amount<=0||amount>=100000)
    {
        cout<<"Please re-enter your amount";
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
```

Comment: Fantastic. +1 my friend... 
I don't get the cin.ignore part... why is there a 10000?

Comment: Nvm... I got to know.
But thank you!

Comment: Notice: I think the `10000`is just a bad habbit. It probably better to do `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()`

Comment: Yea I know,,, but it's alright.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that when you call `cin >> amount` and the input is *not* numeric, the data is left in the buffer. Once your code loops back to the same operation, your read fails again, in an infinite loop.

To fix this problem you need to check the result of `cin >> amount`, like this:

```
if (cin >> amount) {
    ... // do something with amount
} else {
    cin.clear(); // unset failbit
    // Ignore some input before continuing
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```

Reference on the `ignore` function is [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore).

Answer (score 2):

You have to clear the error flag and ignore the characters.

For an example of cin.clear() see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131647/why-would-we-call-cin-clear-and-cin-ignore-after-reading-input).

```
do {
    cout << "Enter a deposit amount (between $0 and $100000) to play game : $";
    cin >> amount;

    if(amount<=0 || amount>=100000) {
        cout << "\nPlease re-enter your amount\n";
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(10000,'\n');
    }
} while(amount<=0 || amount>=100000);
```