# FOR loop without condition value "for (int i = 1; ; i++)" doesn't work properly

Tags: c++, if-statement, for-loop

I found a post where FOR loop is used without CONDITION value. Here is a loop:

```
for (INITIALIZATION; CONDITION; AFTERTHOUGHT) 
{
    // Code for the for-loop's body goes here.
}
```

It's not safe to skip CONDITION value, but if you use `if/else` statement it can be done. Please take a look on my for loop: `for (int i = 1; ; i++)` and implementation inside. For some reason, I don't get proper logic with `if/else` statement.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int boxes;
    int boxes_for_sale;

    cout << "Enter quantity of the boxes in warehouse: > " << flush;
    cin >> boxes;
    cout << "Enter quantity of the boxes for sale: > " << flush;
    cin >> boxes_for_sale;

    for (int i = 1;; i++) {

        if (boxes < boxes_for_sale) {
            cout << "There are not enough boxes in warehouse!" << endl;
            cout << "Enter quantity of the boxes for sale: > " << flush;
            cin >> boxes_for_sale;
        }
        else
            boxes -= boxes_for_sale;
            cout << "Car N:" << i << " is full\n" << "You have " << boxes << "boxes for sale" << endl;

        if (boxes == 0)
            cout << "Sold out!" << endl;
            break;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're missing some curly brackets `{` `}` in a couple of places.

Comment: As @1201ProgramAlarm says, you need braces around your code following the if and else statements. Also, "It doesn't work properly" is not a good problem description. You should add information about *how* it doesn't work and what you expected to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, guys for lack of description. This is my first question here, I'll be more specific next time.

This is what I tried to do.

```
int main() {

    int boxes_in_warehouse;
    int boxes_for_sale;
    cout << "Enter quantity of the boxes in warehouse: " << flush;
    cin >> boxes_in_warehouse;
    cout << "Enter quantity of the boxes for sale: " << flush;
    cin >> boxes_for_sale;

    if (boxes_in_warehouse < boxes_for_sale) {
        cout << "No, Enter quantity of the boxes for sale: " << flush;
        cin >> boxes_for_sale;
    }

    boxes_in_warehouse -= boxes_for_sale;

    while (boxes_in_warehouse > 0) {
        cout << "You have " << boxes_in_warehouse << " left" << endl;
        cout << "Please enter quantity of the boxes for sale again" << endl;
        cin >> boxes_for_sale;
        boxes_in_warehouse -= boxes_for_sale;
    }

    cout << "we are sold out" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The code supposed to run till boxes_in_warehouse == 0 means sold out.

if you can optimize my last code, I will be happy to see your version.

Comment: Three things to note: this isn't really an answer. It would work better as an addendum to your question. Second, note that you do not test that `boxes_for_sale` is less than or equal to `boxes_in_warehouse` in the while loop, allowing for some really dodgy results. Third, none of the `cin >> `s are tested to ensure the user is putting in valid numbers. The user could input a non-number and break your program, probably trapping it in an infinite loop, but the result of reading cin when it is in an error state is undefined.

Comment: Thanks for comments, it's useful info for me. How do I test cin >> for valid number?

Comment: See [Why would we call cin.clear() and cin.ignore() after reading input?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131647/why-would-we-call-cin-clear-and-cin-ignore-after-reading-input) for a good example and how to clean up after bad input. `while (!cin >> boxes_in_warehouse) {cout << "bad input. Try again"<<endl; cin.clear(); cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');} ` will keep asking for a number until the user provides one. There are still a few things wrong with it (user can still put in impossibly long numbers and numbers followed by crap) but should cover what you need

Answer (score 4):

Since you did not specify the desired behaviour of program, I will only state what is happening in the code right now.

important snippets of code that may be doing something unexpected:

```
 for (int i = 1;; i++)
```

This is perfectly legal, but notice there is no termination condition specified. you will run into an infinite loop unless you `break` out of it.

```
else
    boxes -= boxes_for_sale;
    cout << "Car N:" << i << " is full\n" <<
    "You have " << boxes << "boxes for sale" << endl;
```

I can guess based on the indentation that you want both lines to execute only when the if statement preceding the `else` is false, but this is not what is happening.

Since you have not specified the else block with curly braces, only the first statement after the `else` will execute when you need it to. The `cout` will **always** execute.

You have the same issue with:

```
if (boxes == 0)
        cout << "Sold out!" << endl; //will output only if boxes==0
        break; //will break out of loop in any case
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int boxes;
    int boxes_for_sale;

    cout << "Enter quantity of the boxes in warehouse: > " << flush;
    cin >> boxes;
    cout << "Enter quantity of the boxes for sale: > " << flush;
    cin >> boxes_for_sale;

    for (int i = 1;; i++) {

        if (boxes < boxes_for_sale) {
            cout << "There are not enough boxes in warehouse!" << endl;
            cout << "Enter quantity of the boxes for sale: > " << flush;
            cin >> boxes_for_sale;
        }
        else{
            boxes -= boxes_for_sale;
}
            cout << "Car N:" << i << " is full\n" << "You have " << boxes << "boxes for sale" << endl;

        if (boxes == 0)
 {           cout << "Sold out!" << endl;
            break;}

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Explanation of what you did and why highly recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Take care of braces, you need to put braces for each for loop, if statement and else statement.

Also try to take care of indentation for good programming practice.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{

    int boxes;
    int boxes_for_sale;

    cout << "Enter quantity of the boxes in warehouse: > " << flush;
    cin >> boxes;
    cout << "Enter quantity of the boxes for sale: > " << flush;
    cin >> boxes_for_sale;

    for (int i = 1;; i++) {

        if (boxes < boxes_for_sale) 
        {
            cout << "There are not enough boxes in warehouse!" << endl;
            cout << "Enter quantity of the boxes for sale: > " << flush;
            cin >> boxes_for_sale;
        }
        else
        {
            boxes -= boxes_for_sale;
            cout << "Car N:" << i << " is full\n" << "You have " << boxes <<       boxes for sale" << endl;
        }
        if (boxes == 0)
       {
            cout << "Sold out!" << endl;
            break;
       }

    }
    return 0;
}
```