# C++ Program need help to debug

Tags: c++, string, cin, spacing

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

struct football_game

{
    string visit_team;
    int home_score;
    int visit_score;
};

void printMenu();

int main()
{
    int i, totalValues = 0;
    ifstream inputFile;
    string temp = "";

    inputFile.open("games.txt");

    if (!inputFile)
    {
        cout << "Error opening Input file!" << endl;
        exit(101);
    }

    inputFile >> totalValues;
    getline(inputFile, temp);

    cout << "                            *** Football Game Scores *** " << endl << endl;
    cout << " * Total Number of teams : " << totalValues << endl << endl;

    football_game* records = new football_game[totalValues];

    // while (!inputFile.eof())
    // {// == NULL) {

    for (i = 0; i < totalValues; i++)
    {
        getline(inputFile, records[i].visit_team);
        cout << records[i].visit_team << endl;
        inputFile >> records[i].home_score >> records[i].visit_score;
        cout << records[i].home_score << "  " << records[i].visit_score << endl;
        getline(inputFile, temp);
    }
    //}
    cout << endl;


    int choice = 0;
    int avg_home_Score = 0;
    int avg_visit_Score = 0;

    printMenu(); // prints menu


    cout << "Please Enter a choice from the Menu : ";
    cin >> choice;
    cout << endl << endl;

    while (true)
    {
        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1:
                cout << "               Score Table " << endl;
                cout << "         ***********************" << endl << endl;

                cout << "        VISIT_TEAM"
                     << "      "
                     << " HIGH_SCORE"
                     << "   "
                     << "VISIT_SCORE " << endl;
                cout << "       -----------"
                     << "      "
                     << "-----------"
                     << "  "
                     << "------------" << endl;


                for (int i = 0; i < totalValues; i++)
                {
                    cout << '|' << setw(18) << left << records[i].visit_team << "    " << '|'
                         << setw(7) << right << records[i].home_score << "     " << '|' << setw(7)
                         << right << records[i].visit_score << "     " << '|' << endl;
                }

                cout << endl << endl << endl;

                break;
            case 2:
            {
                string team_name;
                cout << "Enter the Team Name  :  ";
                cin >> team_name;
                for (int i = 0; i < totalValues; i++)
                {
                    if (records[i].visit_team == team_name)
                    {

                        cout << "        VISIT_TEAM"
                             << "      "
                             << " HIGH_SCORE"
                             << "   "
                             << "VISIT_SCORE " << endl;
                        cout << "       -----------"
                             << "      "
                             << "-----------"
                             << "  "
                             << "------------" << endl;
                        cout << '|' << setw(18) << left << records[i].visit_team << "    " << '|'
                             << setw(7) << right << records[i].home_score << "     " << '|'
                             << setw(7) << right << records[i].visit_score << "     " << '|'
                             << endl;
                    }
                }
                cout << endl;
                break;
            }
            case 3:
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < totalValues; i++)
                    avg_home_Score += records[i].home_score;
                cout << "Average home_score: " << (avg_home_Score / totalValues) << endl << endl;
                break;
            }
            case 4:
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < totalValues; i++)
                    avg_visit_Score += records[i].visit_score;
                cout << "Average visit_score: " << (avg_visit_Score / totalValues) << endl << endl;
                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                cout << "Please enter valid input !!" << endl;
                break;
            }
        }
        printMenu();
        cin >> choice;
    }
    return 0;
}

void printMenu()
{
    cout << "                      Menu Options                 " << endl;
    cout << "                    ================               " << endl;
    cout << "     1. Print Information of all Games[Table Form] " << endl;
    cout << "     2. Print Information of a Specific Game       " << endl;
    cout << "     3. Print Average points scored by the Home Team during season" << endl;
    cout << "     4. Print Average points scored against the Home Team" << endl << endl << endl;
}
```

Here is the input file i am using

**games.txt**

```
5

SD Mines

21 17

Northern State

10 3

BYU

10 21

Creighton

14 7

Sam Houston State

14 24
```

When i am using the 2nd option (Print Information of a Specific Game) from the output screen,
it ask me to enter the team name and when i enter the team-name.
For example: SD Mines  it gives me an error, but when I enter the team-name with no space like: BYU  it works fine for me.

Comment: what error does it give you?

Comment: it will again print out the menu

Comment: @Z123456789 -- *C++ Program need help to debug* -- Wouldn't this be a good time to learn how to use the debugger that comes with your compiler toolset?

Comment: only when i enter team name : SD Mines or Northern State or Sam Houston State. it works fine when i enter team name : BYU or Creighton. I think the problem is coming because there is a space in SD mines and no space in BYU

Comment: @Z123456789 -- If you believe the problem is with spaces, why are you using all of this code to figure out how to read in a string with spaces?  Write a small, 3 line program that successfully reads in a string with spaces.  Once you learn how to do that, then you apply it to your larger program.

Comment: You can see here that it stops reading at the space: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/eKZK1Prb55X3wX9f

Answer (score 0):

> cin >> team_name;

Takes the input only upto space.

You might want to use [cin.getline()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/**) for taking space separated strings as input.

A small program demonstrating the same :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main ()
{
    std::string name;

    std::cout << "Please, enter your full name: ";
    std::getline (std::cin,name);
    std::cout << "Name is : , " << name << "!\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: so instead of cin>> team_name

Answer (score 0):

std::cin ignores whitespaces by default.

To include spaces in your input try :

```
getline(cin, team_name);
```

This would pick up all the characters in a line until you press enter. This is available in

```
#include<string>
```

Comment: when i do that it dosen't allowed me to enter the team name

Comment: string library has to be included in your program. #include <string>

Comment: `#include <string>` should have been in the original program, regardless of whether `getline` is used or not.

Comment: I have included the #inculde<string> and getline(cin, team_name)

Comment: but its asking to enter the team name and printing out the menu

Comment: try  cin >> noskipws >> team_name;

Answer (score 0):

You need [to flush the `std::cin` buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257091/how-do-i-flush-the-cin-buffer) after reading the `choice`:

```
#include <limits>
//...

cin >> choice;
cin.clear();
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131647/why-would-we-call-cin-clear-and-cin-ignore-after-reading-input) for detailed explanation.

Also, if you want to read strings with spaces from the standard input, replace this:

```
cin >> team_name;
```

with this:

```
getline(cin, team_name);
```

as already mentioned in other answers. No need to flush `std::cin` this time, since you have already read the full line.

Finally, remove extra newlines from your `games.txt`:

```
5
SD Mines
21 17
Northern State
...
```

Comment: I have added the things you mentioned

Comment: but i can only enter team name one time, when i am trying to enter it second time it is giving me an error

Comment: @Z123456789, there are two places with `cin >> choice`. The second time is just the second `cin >> choice` (at the end of the loop), where you likely forgot to flush `std::cin`.

Comment: so at the end of the switch statement do i need to remove the cin>>choice

Comment: @Z123456789, you need to flush it there, too, if you need it there. The idea is to flush `std::cin`'s buffer after reading the numbers.