# endl doesn't seem to execute

Tags: c++, vector, newline

I've read and re-read the code but I can't find a logical conclusion as to why when run, there isn't a newline created between the start and end times. Both positive and negative advice is appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    //start time and end time of shift
    vector <int> vstart;
    vector <int> vend;
    vector <string> days_of_week = {"Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"};
    int start, end;
    while (cin >> start) {
        vstart.push_back(start);
    }
    while (cin >> end) {
        vend.push_back(end);
    }

    for (string d : days_of_week) {
        cout << d << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl << "---------------------------------------------------------\n";
    for (int s : vstart) {
        cout << s << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (int e : vend) {
        cout << e << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: For some specified input, can you please show us the expected and actual output?

Comment: You should use `for(const string& d: days_of_week)` if you wanna avoid redundant copy operation.

Comment: The output should list the days of the week as defined in days_of_week separated by tabs followed by a barrier of dashes then a newline and the start times of each shift followed by a newline and the end times of each shift

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have no `end` times and the first `while` puts everything into `vstart`; you can verify that easily with a debugger. How does your input look like?

Comment: Yeah, the first `while` loop will execute as long as it can successfully extract `int` values. It's consuming all the input before you reach the second `while` loop.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz that seems to make sense. I'm new to this as my name entails. I also tried using an && statement such as while (cin >> start && end) but it also didn't seem to work.

Comment: Perhaps you should use a standard `for` loop for the input of the start and end times, to make sure you only get seven elements of each?

Comment: Also, please *show* (by editing the question) the input and the outputs. Copy-paste it from the terminal. Please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And also please read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude that is a very good suggestion, I'll learn from this mistake and include what kind of inputs I am making as well as the outputs I am expecting. Thank you guys very much for your kind words.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at this portion of code.

```
while (cin >> start) {
    vstart.push_back(start);
}
while (cin >> end) {
    vend.push_back(end);
}
```

In the first loop, you read in values until `cin>>start` reaches an end-of-file byte, or fails in a different way. But you do not clear that fail-state.
You have to call `cin.clear();` to be able to read new input in the second loop.

```
while (cin >> start) {
    vstart.push_back(start);
}
cin.clear();
while (cin >> end) {
    vend.push_back(end);
}
```

Further reading: [Why would we call cin.clear() and cin.ignore() after reading input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131647/why-would-we-call-cin-clear-and-cin-ignore-after-reading-input)

Answer (score 1):

This `while` loop will execute as long as it can successfully extract `int` values. It doesn't know to stop after reading 7 numbers and is putting all your input into `vstart`.

```
while (cin >> start) {
    vstart.push_back(start);
}
```

I think you want something like this `for` loop that includes logic to stop after reading 7 values.

```
for (int i = 0; (i < 7) && (cin >> start); ++i) {
    vstart.push_back(start);
}
```