# Still being prompted after entering a valid input value

Tags: c++

I made this for an assignment but even if I enter a valid input from the desired range I still get prompted. This is happening to both input prompts. I suspect the problem is in the `while` blocks of the `setupGame` function.

```
 #include <iostream>  
 using namespace std;
 bool setupGame(int numberRef, int triesRef);


int main(){
  cout<<"hello world";
  setupGame(4,4);
  cout<<"enough";
}


//SETUP GAME FUNCTION
bool setupGame(int numberRef, int triesRef) { 
 do { 
      cout << "ENTER A NUMBER BETWEEN 1 and 100" << endl; 
      cin >> numberRef;
cin.clear(); 
//your code here 
cout << "You entered: " << numberRef << endl; 
if (numberRef==-1) { 
   cout << "You do not want to set a number " << endl; 
   cout << "so you stopped the program" << endl;  
} 


else if(numberRef >=1 && numberRef <=100) 
   do { 
     cout << "ENTER TRIES BETWEEN 3 and 7" << endl; 
     cin >> triesRef;
     cin.clear();
     //cin.ignore( '\n');   
     cout<< "You entered: "<< triesRef<< endl; 
     if (triesRef==-1) { 
        cout << "You do not want to set tries. "; 
  cout << "so you stopped the program" << endl;
} else if(triesRef <= 3 && triesRef >= 7){
  cout<<"Number of tries should be between 3 and 7";
}

   } 

while(numberRef >=1 && numberRef <=100);{ 

   return true; 
}
} 
   while(triesRef >= 3 && triesRef <= 7);{
return true;
} }
```

Comment: Also add your input and output, expected and actual.

Comment: First of all, please try to reformat your code with some consistent and clear indentation. Secondly, what do you think `do { ... } while (...); { return true; }` would accomplish? That's an *unconditional* `return true;` being executed *after* the loop finish.

Comment: "*I suspect the problem is in the while blocks of the setupGame function.*" Why don't you find out if your suspicion is correct by testing the parts of your code separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're tangling yourself up with these nested loops. Your prompt keeps printing because the while loop:

`while(numberRef >=1 && numberRef <=100)`

is going to keep repeating it's preceding `do` block until you enter a value less than 1 or greater than 100, same goes for the last `while` loop as well.

I assume you're using `cin.clear()` to flush the previous input, if you are then stop it, that is not the purpose of `cin.clear()`. It's instead use to clear the error state of `cin`. Please thoroughly read up on it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131647/why-would-we-call-cin-clear-and-cin-ignore-after-reading-input).

Below is the code to achieve what you want, please observe how I implemented the while loops after each `cin` prompt to ensure that a valid character is entered.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream> 
using namespace std;

bool setupGame(int numberRef, int triesRef);

int main(){
  cout<<"hello world";
  setupGame(4,4);
  cout<<"enough";
}

//SETUP GAME FUNCTION
bool setupGame(int numberRef, int triesRef) { 
    cout << "ENTER A NUMBER BETWEEN 1 and 100" << endl; 
    cin >> numberRef;
        while((numberRef < 1 || numberRef > 100 || cin.fail()) && numberRef != -1) {
            cin.clear(); // Used to clear error state of cin
            cin.ignore(); // Might want to ignore the whole line
            cout<<"Number should be between 1 and 100, or -1 , please try again: ";
            cin>>numberRef;
        }  
    cout << "You entered: " << numberRef << endl; 
    if (numberRef==-1) { 
        cout << "You do not want to set a number " << endl; 
        cout << "so you stopped the program" << endl;  
        }

    if(numberRef >=1 && numberRef <=100) {
        cout << "ENTER TRIES BETWEEN 3 and 7" << endl; 
        cin >> triesRef; 
            while(triesRef < 3 || triesRef > 7 || cin.fail()) {
                cin.clear(); // Used to clear error state of cin
                cin.ignore(); // Might want to ignore the whole line
                cout<<"Tries should be between 3 and 7 , please try again: ";
                cin>>triesRef;
            } 
        cout<< "You entered: "<< triesRef<< endl;

    if (triesRef==-1) { 
        cout << "You do not want to set tries. "; 
        cout << "so you stopped the program" << endl;
        return false;
    } 
}
}
```

Comment: `while((numberRef < 1 || numberRef > 100 || cin.fail()) && numberRef != -1)` is a little broken.  `cin.fail()` can be true (the read failed) and `numberRef != -1` could still allow the loop to be exit even though the -1 in `numberRef` is bogus. If `cin` is errored, you always want to repeat. Nothing good will come of looking at `numberRef`.

Comment: @user4581301 You're absolutely right, an input of `-1a` will exit the loop as if it's just `-1`, for it to be truly fool-proof it would need a lot more work, however this is a cut and dry solution intended to show the OP how to integrate while loops for input checking, are there better ways? Absolutely. Would I do it different? Yes. However based on the OP code and approach I don't take him/her as an expert on the language, a complex and in depth answer wouldn't explain his/her current errors.

Comment: The likes of -*1a* is not the concern. I worry about `numberRef` being -1 after a completely failed read.*-1a* is valid. The program read *-1* and left *a* in the stream. *kartoffel* on the other hand fails utterly and if `numberRef` wound up -1 for whatever reason, then `while((-1 < 1 || -1 > 100 || cin.fail())  && -1 != -1)` is `while((true || shorted || shorted)  && false)` The loop existed on a failed read. check `cin`'s state first, then and only then can you trust the value in `numberRef`.