# im trying to display array of object but it's giving wrong output

Tags: c++, new-operator

i'm trying to create array of object and display it but for some reason it's giving wrong out put 
i think i'm using the new operator wrong way but i'not sure what's wrong

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
class X {
    string s;
    int b;
public:

    void set(string s,int b ) {
        this->s = s;
        this->b = b;
    }
    void display() {
        cout << this->s << ' ' << this->b << '\n';
    }

};

int main() 
{
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        int n;
        cin >> n;
        X* a = new X[n];
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            string s; int b;
            cin >> s >> b;
            a[i].set(s, b);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            a[i].display();
        }

    }
}
```

input:
1
3
abhi 1
omkar 2
ritesh 3

output:
ritesh 3
0
0

Comment: Did you try to use `std::endl` instead of `\n` in your display() method ? Otherwise the program is not forced to display all the contents.

Comment: *it's giving wrong out put* -- We have no idea what the input is, thus the output you're getting cannot be determined, given what you've posted.

Comment: Memory leak alert. `delete[] a;`... or use `std::unique_ptr<X[]>`.... or `std::vector`.

Comment: You might want to take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131647/why-would-we-call-cin-clear-and-cin-ignore-after-reading-input

Comment: Take a closer look at your indexing until you see the problem. (Lesson to learn: use visually distinct and meaningful identifiers.)

Comment: Since you now have two (identically) wrong answers, I'm going to point out that you have written `a[i]` where you should have `a[j]` in the inner loop, and vote to close this as a typo.

Answer (score 1):

You have to instantiate each and every object in the array of objects. 
And try to use `getline` function to get the input of the string.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
class X {
    string s;
    int b;
public:

    void set(string s,int b ) {
        this->s = s;
        this->b = b;
    }
    void display() {
        cout << this->s << ' ' << this->b << '\n';
    }

};

int main() 
{
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        int n;
        cin >> n;
        X *a[n];
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            a[j] = new X;
            string s; int b;            
            cin >> s >> b;
            a[j]->set(s, b);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            a[i]->display();
        }

    }
}
```

Hope this might helps : )

Comment: They are instantiated (default-constructed) in OP's code. (Note that OP does not have an array of pointers, but of `X`s.) Also, your variable-length array is non-standard.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the initialization of the array. You use `X* a = new X[n];` as initialization of pointer to class X. For a correct initialization you have to use the following lines :

```
X* a[n];
for(int k = 0 ; i < n ; ++i){
    a[k] = new X; 
}
```

Pay attention to the use of pointer. Probably you don't need it. In the case you don't need it, you can use the following line to initialize the array: `X a[n];`
Now you can use the array without pointer so you can substitute the ->(arrow) with the .(point) to call functions or access variables of the class.

Another tips: use `std::endl` instead of `'\n'` in the display function or in general in the `std::cout`.

Comment: That's not where the problem is; all the objects are properly initialized.