# Use of getline to read a string with white spaces in a structure

Tags: c++, cin, getline

I want to read strings with white spaces into members of a structure. Tried using `getline` but both the output statements are clubbed with a single `cin` for both. As per the similar posts here, tried using `cin.ignore`, but the input is not read into the member of the structure. Pls help. It's a part of my assignment and I'm a beginner in C++. This is how my code looks like:

```
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
struct book {
  string title, author;
  int no_of_pages, year;
  float price;
};
int main() {
  int N;
  cout << "Enter the no. of books whose details are to be entered:" << endl;
  cin >> N;
  book b[N];
  int x;
  for (x = 0; x < N; x++) {
    cout << "Enter the title of book #" << x + 1 << ":" << endl;
    getline(cin, (b[x].title));
    // cin.ignore();
    cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
    cout << "Enter the author's name:" << endl;
    getline(cin, (b[x].author));
    cout << "Enter the no. of pages:" << endl;
    cin >> b[x].no_of_pages;
    cout << "Enter the price of book:" << endl;
    cin >> b[x].price;
    cout << "Enter the year of publishing" << endl;
    cin >> b[x].year;
  }
  for (x = 0; x < N; x++) {
    cout << "\n\n";
    cout << "The details of book" << x + 1 << " are:" << endl;
    cout << "Title          :" << b[x].title << endl;
    cout << "Author         :" << b[x].author << endl;
    cout << "No. of pages   :" << b[x].no_of_pages << endl;
    cout << "Price          :" << b[x].price << endl;
    cout << "Publishing year:" << b[x].year << endl;
    cout << "---------------------------------------------";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you tell more about your expected and actual output.

Answer (score 0):

There's no point in using `cin.ignore()` in between two calls to `getline`. `ignore` is used to discard remaining characters **after** numeric input. So the place to use it is after numeric input and before the next `getline`. Like this

```
cout << "Enter the title of book #" << x + 1 << ":" << endl;
getline(cin, (b[x].title));
cout << "Enter the author's name:" << endl;
getline(cin, (b[x].author));
cout << "Enter the no. of pages:" << endl;
cin >> b[x].no_of_pages;
cout << "Enter the price of book:" << endl;
cin >> b[x].price;
cout << "Enter the year of publishing" << endl;
cin >> b[x].year;
cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
```

That said I would just read everything using `getline`, then convert the strings to numbers where needed. That's simpler and cleaner, all you need to know is how to convert a string to an integer, which you can easily research for yourself.

Comment: So what do I do now??

Comment: I don't understand, what problem do you have now?

Answer (score 0):

There are two places you should put `cin.ignore` in your code:

```
  cout << "Enter the no. of books whose details are to be entered:" << endl;
  cin >> N;
  // First cin.ignore here
  cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
```

```
    cout << "Enter the year of publishing" << endl;
    cin >> b[x].year;
    // Second cin.ignore here
    cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
```

Besides this I see two more problems in your code:

- `#include <string>` not `<string.h>`
- add `#include <iostream>`

Why `cin.ignore` is necessary? User is expected to provide new line ('\n') delimited input. When `getline` is used, it leaves the input stream in such a state that the next attempt to read input from stream will start at next line. This is not true for `operator >>`. What `int x; cin >> x;` does here is it reads only the integer not the new line character present right after the integer. Hence, the next attempt to read will continue within the same line. `getline` will then find no character before new line and hence will fetch an empty string. To avoid this and to effectively start reading from the next line, `cin.ignore` is necessary.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I think I've solved my problem. But I don't get what cin.ignore exactly does in a program. If you could all help please..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131647/why-would-we-call-cin-clear-and-cin-ignore-after-reading-input Does this help?

Comment: Added a brief description of why `cin.ignore` is necessary. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes it did.  Thanks a lot