# How do I check a valid user input?

Tags: c++, loops, validation, user-input

I was doing a project for an online course and the final project was to make a Build Your Adventure program where the user has choices and they lead to endings. I deleted the *huge* intro and just now copied the part where I have the first choice. So basically, it all works when I don't write valid numbers, but when I write in a letter... the whole program begins an infinite loop. Please help!
Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    int c1;

    std::cout << "After what felt like thirty minutes of "
                 "walking you reached a wall. Yes, a wall.\n"
                 "A wall so tall and wide you couldn't imagine "
                 "climbing over it or walking around it.\n";
    std::cout << "Luckly, you see two animals willing to help you.\n"
                 "1) A mole that can build a tunnel under the wall\n"
                 "2) An eagle that can carry you over the wall\n";
    std::cout << "Enter 1 or 2 to make a choice: ";
    std::cin >> c1;

    while (!(std::cin >> c1) || c) {
        std::cout << "Error! Please enter a valid input!\n";
        std::cout << "Enter 1 or 2 to make a choice: ";
        std::cin >> c1;
        std::cout << "\n"
    }
```

Comment: And also when I try input the correct value it is also wrong...I am new to C++ so I need help

Comment: If you enter a non-digit, the formatted input of `int` fails and sets the `std::cin` into fail state. You have to `clear()` the error _and_ to `ignore()` the wrong input (to empty your input queue and get rid of the wrong stuff).

Comment: Can you just briefly show what you mean. Is it after or before the new input?

Comment: FYI: [SO: Why would we call cin.clear() and cin.ignore() after reading input?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5131654/7478597)

Comment: So I just need to add those two lines before the new input?

Comment: IMHO, you should distinguish `std::cin >> c1` (it returns `false` when formatted input failed and hence you need to `clear()` the error flag and `ignore()` the wrong input) from a valid integer for which you need a range check. E.g. if you input `7` this leaves the formatted input in good state but your range check should sort it out, shouldn't it.

Comment: Yepp. `cin` is a global variable in `namespace std`. So, everytime you use it you should prefix it with its scope -> `std::cin` (regardless if you use it with `>>` or call member functions for it).

Comment: [**Sample on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7f112d45c7814c1d). Please note, in your code, you do `std::cin >> c1;` (without error check) before `while (!(std::cin >> c1) || c) {`. So, these are two inputs to `c1` but you want only one.

Comment: JohnFilleau is there a way to send codes to specific people? If you want I can send you my finished version.

Comment: You can add a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Btw. if you want to address specific people in comments you have to prefix their name with an `@`. In this case, they will get a notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you input invalid inputs for `int`, the stream goes into failed state and can't read further inputs. So you have to clear the error state of the stream and ignore anything left in the input stream.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() {

    int c1;

    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter 1 or 2 to make a choice: ";

        if ((std::cin >> c1) && (c1 == 1 || c1 == 2)) break;
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        std::cout << "Error! Please enter a valid input!\n";
    }

    // Now c1 is either 1 or 2 
}
```