# Getting loop to redisplay message c++

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, while-loop, do-while

I am trying to get a program to display a menu with options, then given the user input, display a certain message. After it displays their message I want the loop to go back to displaying the message until they choose the quit option. How do I get the loop to return to displaying the menu after any choice of 1-3?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;


int main(){
int menu_choice;
cout << "Select a numerical option:" << endl << "=== menu ===" << endl << "1. Fox" << endl << "2. Bunny" << endl << "3. Sloth" << endl << "4. Quit" << endl;
cin >> menu_choice;
while (menu_choice >= 1 && menu_choice <= 4)
{
    while (menu_choice == 1)
    {
        cout << "1 work" << endl;
        menu_choice = 0;
        continue;
    }
    while (menu_choice == 2)
    {
        cout << "2 work" << endl;
        menu_choice = 0;
        continue;
    }
    while (menu_choice == 3)
    {
        cout << "3 work" << endl;
        menu_choice = 0;
        continue;
    }
    while (menu_choice == 4)
    {
        cout << "4 work" << endl;
        menu_choice = 0;
        continue;
    }
}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is just crazy imho `while (menu_choice == 1)
    {
        cout << "1 work" << endl;
        menu_choice = 0;
        continue;
    }` - why would you use a `while` loop here? You set the loop condition to false unconditionally. And what's that `continue` for? This is just bonkers.

Comment: That's a lot of whiles :O most of them are useless. Did you learn about `if` or `switch` yet? It might help you for your menu_choice checks.

Comment: Looks like you wanted to use `if`s or a `switch` rather than those inner `while` loops. Rewrite with a `switch` and add a `default` case to handle what happens if none of the options are taken and then see if you still need to ask this question.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is displaying the menu only 1 time.  If the user enters an invalid choice, you exit right away.  If the user enters a valid choice, you do the chosen work, but then you exit rather than display the menu again.  All of your `while..continue` loops are completely useless, they only run 1 time at most, setting the `menu_choice` to 0, which breaks your outer `while` loop so it runs only 1 time as well.

You need an outer loop that runs continuously, displaying the menu each time, until you are actually ready to exit.

You should also replace the useless `while..continue` loops with `if/else` blocks, or better a single `switch` block.

Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int menu_choice;

    do
    {
        cout << "Select a numerical option:" << endl
             << "=== menu ===" << endl
             << "1. Fox" << endl
             << "2. Bunny" << endl
             << "3. Sloth" << endl
             << "4. Quit" << endl;

        if (!(cin >> menu_choice))
        {
            menu_choice = 0;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }

        switch (menu_choice)
        {
            case 1:
                cout << "1 work" << endl;
                break;

            case 2:
                cout << "2 work" << endl;
                break;

            case 3:
                cout << "3 work" << endl;
                break;

            case 4:
                cout << "4 work" << endl;
                break;

            default:
                cout << "Bad choice! Try again" << endl;
                break;
        }
    }
    while (menu_choice != 4);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Remy Lebeau was quicker posting and his answer is well written, but since I was done writing the code and you might benefit looking at different implementations I'm posting the code. I deliberately chose not to use switch since you might not have seen it before.

```cpp
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    bool quit = false;
    int menu_choice;

    while(!quit) {
        cout << "Select a numerical option:" << endl
             << "=== menu ===" << endl
             << "1. Fox" << endl
             << "2. Bunny" << endl
             << "3. Sloth" << endl
             << "4. Quit" << endl;
        if(cin >> menu_choice) {
            if(menu_choice == 1) {
                cout << "1 work" << endl;
            }
            if(menu_choice == 2) {
                cout << "2 work" << endl;
            }
            if(menu_choice == 3) {
                cout << "3 work" << endl;
            }
            if(menu_choice == 4) {
                cout << "Bye" << endl;
                quit = true;  // Set quit to true to stop the while loop
            } else {
                cout << "Invalid number" << endl;
            }

        } else {
            cout << "Bad input" << endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the `cin.ignore` and `cin.clear` are important and often confuse people new to this. Read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131647/why-would-we-call-cin-clear-and-cin-ignore-after-reading-input) for the details.