# How do I terminate input without crowding cin with a value?

Tags: c++

Mostly, I'm trying to figure out how to terminate input of a specific type without having to write in some character. Eg

```cpp
for (int I; std::cin >> I;)
{
    List.pushback(I);
}
double Value{};
std::cin >> Value;
```

If I want to terminate input for the first part, it seems `std::cin` keeps whatever I type to tell it to stop taking input, and directly throws it in Value without asking for a new input. Any way to fix that?

Edit for example clarification:
Input:

```
12
34
3
```

some random character that stops input

```
23.5
```

Desired Result

List contains `{12;34;3}`

Value contains `23.5`

Actual result

List contains `{12;34;3}`

Value contains some random character that stops input now converted

Comment: What is the input and expected output? Please provide [mcve].

Comment: When `std::cin >> I` fails on "some random character" you need to clear cin's error state and consume the bad input. [Why would we call cin.clear() and cin.ignore() after reading input?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5131654)