# The while loop in C++ skips the user input line

Tags: c++, while-loop, switch-statement

If you enter a character as the input for the first question the switch statement should throw you into the default clause, and it does. But after that, the following while loop just keeps running without waiting for user input. Why is this?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Difficulty Levels\n\n";
    cout << "1 - Easy\n";
    cout << "2 - Normal\n";
    cout << "3 - Hard\n\n";

    int choice;
    cout << "Choice: ";
    cin >> choice;

    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
        cout << "You picked Easy.\n";
        break; // if no break, the code will evaluate choice in following cases
    case 2:
        cout << "You picked Normal.\n";
        break;
    case 3:
        cout << "You picked Hard.\n";
        break;
    default: // execute this if choice doesn't match any condition
        cout << "You made an illegal choice.\n";
    }
    
    char again = 'y'; // setting to "y" does not work !
    while (again == 'y')
    {
        cout << "\n**Played an exciting game**";
        cout << "\nDo you want to play again? (y/n): ";
        cin >> again;
    }
    cout << "\nOkay, bye.";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `cin >> choice;` If the user gets the input in an error state here by typing "frog" instead  of a number your code does not clear it. It remains in an error state and the while loop will loop forever.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131647/why-would-we-call-cin-clear-and-cin-ignore-after-reading-input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131647/why-would-we-call-cin-clear-and-cin-ignore-after-reading-input)

Comment: Your code will run with `std::cin.clear(); 
 std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` included after the `switch` block as pointed out in the duplicate. I would additionally recommend you to consult the [learncpp tutorial](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/stdcin-and-handling-invalid-input/).

Comment: Minor point, concerning that comment after the first `break;`: the code won't "evaluate choice"; it simply continues executing, going past the next `case` statement. A `case` statement is just a label; it has no other significance.